# Spring boot Forwarding a received MultiPartFile to Feign Client

Tags: spring, multipart, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Is it possible to forward a received MultiPartFile item from a REST resource to a Feign Client and expect it to work?

I'm in a situation that I need to get a MultiPartFile request from client via an API gateway in my microservice, then pass it to an external service and after getting response from the external service need to do some extra works in the main middle microservice and respond to the client.

Microservice REST API:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class VisionApiTestResource {

    ....

    @PostMapping("/vision-test/upload-image")
    public ResponseEntity<VisionApiTestResultDTO> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) {
        VisionApiTestResultDTO visionApiTestResultDTO = visionApiTestService.testVisionApi(file);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(visionApiTestResultDTO);
    }

    ....

}
```

The service which is Calling the Feign client

```java
@Service
public class VisionApiTestService {

    ...

    public VisionApiTestResultDTO testVisionApi(MultipartFile multipartFile) {

        BackgroundRemoverResultDTO backgroundRemoverResultDTO = backgroundRemoverClient.removeBackground(multipartFile);

        ...
    }

}
```

My Feign Client:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "BackgroundRemover", url = "http://localhost:8000")
public interface BackgroundRemoverClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/background_removal/remove_background/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    BackgroundRemoverResultDTO removeBackground(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile untouchedImageFile);

}
```

and this is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
        at com.whereandshare.kiosk.kioskservice.service.VisionApiTestService.testVisionApi(VisionApiTestService.java:37)
        at com.whereandshare.kiosk.kioskservice.service.VisionApiTestService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$193667fb.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem forwarding a MultiPartFile you received from spring boot REST endpoint by feign client.

And the printed stacktrace has nothing to do with feign and spring. It was a minor silly mistake I did after getting back the result from the feign.